# Why thread.sleep make problems to my gui?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I have a memory game in java  and i want to freeze my gui , but i use sleep theading and my gui freeze before my gui update..

I want to open the second card of a memory game and when i set the icon of button to that i want the user se i want it to keep it for some sec. I use thread.sleep but method setback never appear.

```
if(logic.openCards(i,j)){
           tofindCards.get(e.getActionCommand()).setBack();
       }
        if(logic.getCardstoChooseReaming()==0){
            try {
                java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            //some other code
                }
            }
```

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding this properly, you're saying that calling the `sleep` method permanently freezes your GUI, but you only want to freeze it temporarily?

Comment: Sleeping the UI thread is not the correct way to accomplish what you want. Flipping the card should schedule a task to be completed asynchronously after 1 second which then puts the card back face down.

Comment: okey and how can i do that?

Comment: [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)